# My browsers display math formulae in Wikipedia pages in Latex format rather than compiled form

Tags: wikipedia

For some time I have noticed that formulas in the Wikipedia pages are shown in LaTeX format rather than compiled form.
I have checked with different browsers like IE, Firefox, Chrome.
In all browsers same problem.
This happens quite often though not always.

Answer (score 2):

This is something to do with your preferences. You can [change them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-rendering) (under the Math section) to the method of rendering that you prefer.